# Is there anyway to represent a void return type using ProducesResponseType attribute with swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I'm trying to use the `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute to decorate my API endpoints in Swagger. However I have endpoints that return a status code and nothing else, and I want my Swagger docs to reflect this.

The problem is I can't find a way to make swagger represent the void return type.

Doing something like `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]` with no type argument causes swagger to produce an example return type

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "status": 0,
  "detail": "string",
  "instance": "string",
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```

I don't want this.

Some of the other things I've tried include:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)] //Produces the same example return type
[ProducesResponseType(null, StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)] //Runtime error, value can't be null
```

Comment: Try using a code other than 400. By default there's special handling for the 400 code for ApiController with MVC +API Explorer (which swagger leverages) that sends a Problem Details response (which is what u are seeing). There's an option to disable but I forget it offhand.. it's on the `ApiBehaviorOptions` class. The right thing to do is to specify no response type. Also I highly recommend switching to the Swagger Annotations library which makes annotating your controllers easier and more obvious what you'd do in these cases

Comment: To add to the above comment, it's also possible to override the default `ProblemDetails` response, as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors#client-error-response